# Narrow `string` to `keyof T` in type guard (hasOwnProperty)

Tags: typescript

I have a `string` user input which should be a key of an object.

```
const validInputOptions = {
    "admin": "Admin",
    "guest": "Guest",
    "restricted": "Restricted Guest",
    "view_only": "Restricted Guest - View Only",
};

const userInput = getUserInput(); // <-- userInput is a string
verify(userInput); // <-- throws new error if user input is invalid
const option = validInputOptions[userInput]; // <-- tsc would still complain here `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type ...`
```

the problem is to tell the tsc that the user input can be used safely as index for `validInputOptions`

Comment: `function verify(key: PropertyKey): asserts key is keyof validInputOptions { if (!(key in validInputOptions)) { throw Error('Invalid key ' + key); } }`

Comment: I see that you've answered your own question, but it would still be nice if the code here constituted a [mcve] that others could use to demonstrate the issue themselves. With `getUserInput()` undeclared, it's hard for anyone to check that the problem exists and that the answer solves it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad the assert guard is great idea, but the tsc kept throwing me this error `TS2775: Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation.`. i'm trying to call it with both `userInput` and `validInputOptions`

Comment: Sorry, typo needs to be `asserts key is keyof typeof validInputOptions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the type guard which I've created (there is official issue on typescript https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12892 that explains why the tsc itself does not narrow the type for `in` operator and for `hasOwnProperty`)

```
const isKeyOf =
    <ObjectType extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>
    (object: ObjectType, property: PropertyKey): property is keyof ObjectType => {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property);
    };
```

so this is the usage:

```
if (!isKeyOf(validInputOptions, userInput)) {
    throw new Error(`invalid input`);
}

// now this is safe to use, userInput is narrowed to `keyof typeof validInputOptions`
const option = validInputOptions[userInput];
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work as well:

```js
function isKeyOf<T extends object>(obj: T, key: PropertyKey): key is keyof T {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(key)
}
```